# How to find the two numbers from two select forms in any order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I want to use the two numbers from my two select forms, but they don't have to be in order (probably not the right words). Is there an easier way to do this:

```
if ((a.indexOf(select1) > -1 && b.indexOf(select2) > -1) || (b.indexOf(select1) > -1 && a.indexOf(select2) > -1) || (a.indexOf(select1) > -1 && a.indexOf(select2) > -1))
 {
    //do something;
 }
```

Right now I will have 14 else if's with more of this unless there is an easier way. I just need it to find ab or ba, cd or dc, whatever is chosen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u elaborate more on "two select forms"?

Comment: `<select name="marked" id="marked">
  <option value="">SELECT</option>
  <option>201</option>
  <option>206</option>
  <option>224</option>
  <option>319</option>
  </select>
  <select name="marked1" id="marked1">
  <option>SELECT</option>
  <option>201</option>
  <option>206</option>
  <option>224</option>
  <option>319</option>
  </select>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>`

Comment: i mean what is required from them? are you comparing them both if they are of same value?

Comment: the options are stored as variables a-s. Both forms have the same options, but if 2 different numbers get chosen, I need to be able to check both ways. For instance, if form1 is 201 and form2 is 319, that would translate to form1 =a and form2=b, which would display the number 4145. This is a form for aluminum fillers for tig welding. You would select your two base metals from the select forms and the appropriate filler metal would be displayed.

Comment: Also, if form1=319 and form2=201 it would be b a which would still need to display 4145.

Answer (score 0):

Since both selects have numbers only we can convert them to integers and then compare, which is easier than string comparison.

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('marked').value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('marked1').value);

if(!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)) {
  if(a<b) {
    alert("marked select is greater than marked1!");
  } else if(b>a) {
    alert("marked1 select is greater than marked!");
  } else {
    alert("marked & marked1 select have same values selected!");
  }
} else {
  alert("select options in both selects!");
}
```